# Mike42/Escpos Class 'Escpos\CapabilityProfile' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, printing, escpos, classnotfound

Please help. I want to create print function with Codeigniter 4 using mike42/escpos

But the class not found.

This is error message

[Erro message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIzWe.png)

This is my Folder directory

[Folder Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AllgP.png)

This is my Autoload file

[Autoload file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pbnl.png)

This is my controller file

[namespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XyLm.png)

[Controller file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lahVu.png)

And this is my printer configuration

[printer configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f67av.png)

Help me, please.  Thank you !

I want to create POS application with direct print using mike42/escpos

Comment: You should copy-paste your code instead of posting screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CapabilityProfile` class' full name is `Mike42\Escpos\CapabilityProfile` (namespace + classname in the `CapabilityProfile.php` file).

`'Escpos' => APPPATH . 'ThirdParty/Mike42/Escpos'` tells the autoloader to look for classes which' full name starts with `Escpos` in the `ThirdParty/Mike42/Escpos` folder, but there are no classes which' full name starts with `Escpos` in that folder, they all start with `Mike42\Escpos`. That is why it can't find the class when you try to `use Escpos\CapabilityProfile;`.

You need to change the array in your `Autoload.php` file to:

```
$psr4 = [
    'App'           => APPPATH,
    APP_NAMESPACE   => APPPATH,
    'Config'        => APPPATH . 'Config',
    'Mike42\Escpos' => APPPATH . 'ThirdParty/Mike42/Escpos',
];
```

And the use statements in your controller to:

```
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\CapabilityProfile;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
```